# lipo request on upload to app store

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to Xcode 8.  When I upload my project to iTunesConnect, I get the following screen: What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Hey @Nelson Capes, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

> What is going on here?

Well, `Xcode` needs to execute `lipo` or another command, but cannot find such tool.
More info about what `lipo` tool is, you can find by running next command in your `Terminal`

```
man lipo
```

> The  lipo command creates or operates on `universal` (multi-architec-
>          ture) files.  It only ever produces one output file, and  never  alters
>          the  input  file.
>
> The  operations that `lipo` performs are:
>    - listing the architecture types in a universal file;
>    - creating  a  single  universal file from one or more input files;
>    - thinning out a single universal file to one specified architecture type;
>    - and extracting,  replacing,  and/or removing architectures types from the   input file to create a single new universal output file.

It seems that your development `Command Line Tools` are out of date.
So you need to update them, try to run next command in your `Terminal` or press `Install` button from your pop-up dialog window.

`$ xcode-select --install`

After successful install go to the next directory to check for a `lipo` tool presense

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

Please note that is the root `/Library`, not user `~/Library`.
If you want to see commands available to you, they’re all in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/`